# Check for availablity of #warning preprocessor

Tags: c, warnings, c-preprocessor, compile-time, preprocessor-directive

I am going to use `#warning` in my portable **C** code for generating compile time warnings. But `#warning` is not supported in all platforms. Is there any way to find whether `#warning` is supported in that platform.

```
#ifdef warning     //expecting similar check, not exactly this
#warning ("my message")
#endif
```

Because I will be compiling my code in so many platforms, in some platform it may give compilation error if its not supported. If some macro are available to find the availability of `#warning` then I will be able to avoid build failure in platforms where it's not supported.

Comment: Are you talking about passing source-code or binaries?

Comment: I am talking about the `#warning` pre processor in C langauge.

Comment: It is not in the C language at all.  It's preprocessor support in specific compiler(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to check for support:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
# define HAVE_WARNING
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_WARNING
# pragma message("some warning")
#endif
```

Add more compiler-specific checks to the first `#if` when needed.

Comment: Which version of MSVC supports #warning instead of #pragma message("Warning...") ?   I believe this is incorrect unless it's a recent change.

Comment: @RandyHoward Right, MSVC doesnt have it. At least for 2005,2008,2010 and 2012 versions. But it has `#pragma message`. But overall approach is correct: the feature has to be enabled/disabled based on compiler used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma message("Warning...")
#pragma message "Oh NO!"
```

Are both supported by GCC and MSVC.  Some please comment on Clang?  I don't have a current version.

Comment: @Joachim - thanks.  +1 It is difficult to keep up with every compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`#warning` is a gcc extension mainly, although some others may support.  Microsoft will require something like `#pragma message` instead.  You can not call it "portable" if you mean a standard C version rather than just where gcc is available.